# slider shows one extra condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have html file like this:

```
<ul class="slider-section__toggle-ctas">
          <li class="slider-section__toggle-cta active"><span>red</span></li>
          <li class="slider-section__toggle-cta"><span>green</span></li>
          <li class="slider-section__toggle-cta"><span>blue</span></li>
        </ul>
```

and js like this:

```
const imagesSlider = () => {
let nextBtn = "";

if ($(".slider-section__toggle-cta").text().length !== 0) {
      nextBtn = $(".active").next();
    } 

if ($(".slider-section__toggle-cta").text().length === 0){
      nextBtn = $(".slider-section__toggle-cta:first");
    }

console.log($(".active").text().length)

$('.active').removeClass('active');

nextBtn.addClass("active");

}
setInterval(imagesSlider, 3000);
```

there is one extra condition according to that console.log() that i included in the code, and i don't know how to fix it,
so basically when the length is 3 it shows the green, when the length is 5 it shows blue and when the length is 4 it shows nothing!(that's the problem), I want to go back to the first li with "red" text here,

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, I made a snippet for you, can you please edit it and create a [mre], it will greatly help to understand the problem and get help...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're checking the `.slider-section__toggle-cta` text size which is always not empty in the following `if` statment.

`if ($(".slider-section__toggle-cta").text().length === 0)`

Use it this way:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider-section__toggle-ctas">
  <li class="slider-section__toggle-cta active"><span>red</span></li>
  <li class="slider-section__toggle-cta"><span>green</span></li>
  <li class="slider-section__toggle-cta"><span>blue</span></li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
    
const imagesSlider = () => {
  let nextBtn = "";
 
  if ($(".active").text().length !== 0) {
    nextBtn = $(".active").next();
  }

  if ($(".active").next().text().length === 0) {
    nextBtn = $(".slider-section__toggle-cta:first");
  }

  console.log($(".active").text().length)

 
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  nextBtn.addClass("active");

}
setInterval(imagesSlider, 3000);

</script>
```

Look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pkbxyh9u/1/)

Comment: same issue, doesn't work

Comment: Works fine for me. I add the jsfiddle link. check it out and let me know if have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it using

```
  if ($(".active").next().text().length !== 0) {
      nextBtn = $(".active").next();
    } 

    
    if ($(".active").next().text().length === 0) {
        nextBtn = $(".slider-section__toggle-cta:first");
      }
```